# Como pegar o valor de um atributo estático dentro de um método quando tem uma variável com o mesmo nome nesse método?

Tags: java, método, atributos, static

Quando é um atributo não estático pode-se usar o `this.nomeAtributo`.

Exemplo:

```
public class NomeDaClasse {
    private String atributo;

    public void (String atributo) {
        fazerAlgo(this.atributo);
        fazerAlgo(atributo);
    }

}
```

Porem, como se faz para pegar se o esse atributo for estático?

```
public class NomeDaClasse {
    private static String atributo;

    public void (String atributo) {
        fazerAlgo(?.atributo);
        fazerAlgo(atributo);
    }

}
```

Comment: `NomeDaClasse.atributo`

Comment: Sim! Tinha me esquecido. Valeu!